# React Native: how to make patch versions match on iOS/Android?

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store-connect, google-play-console, semantic-versioning

I'm on version 4.4.33.3 of my React Native app. In XCode this works fine:

[image]

but for Android, if I make the `versionCode` 3 if prevents me from uploading to Google Play because I've already uploaded one with `versionCode` 3. It makes me increment the `versionCode` every time. So right now I'm forced to use 7 or above, but when users download this Android build it shows 4.4.33.7. Is there a way to avoid this mismatch between versions in iOS vs Android?

[image]